# How to get JSON from request Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use this method:

```
public function store(CreateEvent $request)
{
    dd($request->json()->all());

}
```

My requests is:

```
{"name":"etegjgjghjghj","date":"2019-03-08"}
```

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

As response I get blank page in Chrome network without response data.

I tried this:

```
public function store(CreateEvent $request){ dd('test'); }
```

Comment: You want to convert your inputs to a json?

Comment: Then your data isn't passed correctly

Comment: What is `CreateEvent` Class? Never heard before

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this:

```
public function store(CreateEvent $request)
{
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

Comment: It works, so to get specific property should I do: `$request->date`?

Comment: If it's json it's better to use `$request->input('date');` but you can use also `$request->date`. You can see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Why I can not get ` dd($request->name);`, it return blank

Comment: With json data and `Content/Type` set to `application/json` the advised way to retrieve input is with `$request->input('date')` you can read in the doc I linked above

Answer (score 2):

If the request has header 'Content-Type: application/json' and it's a valid JSON, then laravel will convert it automatically.  You don’t need to do any extra job. 

But you have to make sure the JSON is correct. Because JSON must contain double quoted strings not single (if has any)

Next thing, your form validation probably shooting 422 request which by default redirects back to previous page. you can try `dd` in the form request class

Comment: I was using single quotes. Chaging for double quotes resolved the issue for me. Thx.